# How to serve static files with nginx inside of a docker container?

Tags: nginx, static, docker

I'm using boot2docker since I'm running Mac OSX. I can't figure out how serve up static files using nginx that is running inside a docker container (that also contains the static assets, like my html and js).

I have four docker containers being spun up with this **docker-compose.yml**:

```
web:
   build: ./public
   links: 
     - nodeapi1:nodeapi1
   ports:
     - "80:80"

nodeapi1:
   build: ./api
   links:
     - redis
     - db
   ports:
     - "5000:5000"
   volumes:
     - ./api:/data

redis:
   image: redis:latest
   ports:
     - "6379:6379"

db:
   image: postgres:latest
   environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: root
   ports:
     - "5432:5432"
```

This is my **nginx.conf**:

```
worker_processes auto;

daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  upstream node-app {
    ip_hash;
    server 192.168.59.103:5000;
  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;
    root /var/www;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
      expires 1d;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass http://node-app;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

  }
}
```

My **Dockerfile** for my web build (which contains my nginx.conf and static assets):

```
# Pull nginx base image
FROM nginx:latest

# Expost port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy custom configuration file from the current directory
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy static assets into var/www
COPY ./dist /var/www
COPY ./node_modules /var/www/node_modules

# Start up nginx server
CMD ["nginx"]
```

The contents of the ./dist folder is a bundle.js file and an index.html file. The file layout is:

```
public
  -- Dockerfile
  -- nginx.conf
  -- dist (directory)
    -- bundle.js
    -- index.html
  -- node_modules
    ...various node modules
```

It is properly sending requests to my node server (which is also in a docker container, which is why my upstream server points to the boot2docker ip), but I'm just getting 404s for attempts to retrieve my static assets.

I'm lost as to next steps. If I can provide any information, please let me know.

Answer (score 13):

Your issue isn't related to docker but to your nginx configuration.

In your nginx config file, you define `/var/www/` as the document root (I guess to serve your static files). But below that you instruct nginx to act as a reverse proxy to your node app **for all requests**.

Because of that, if you call the `/index.html` URL, nginx won't even bother checking the content of `/var/www` and will forward that query to nodejs.

Usually you want to distinguish requests for static content from requests for dynamic content by using a URL convention. For instance, all requests starting with `/static/` will be served by nginx while anything else will be forwarded to node. The nginx config file would then be:

```
worker_processes auto;

daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  upstream node-app {
    ip_hash;
    server 192.168.59.103:5000;
  }
  server {
    listen 80;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
      expires 1d;
    }

    location /static/ {
      alias /var/www/;
      index index.html;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass http://node-app;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Adopting your configuration, I'm now getting a 404 from my node server along with some chunky response from my nginx server: 

192.168.59.3 - - [04/Aug/2015:10:43:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 13 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2304.125 Safari/537.36"

Comment: the config example in my answer is an example that would work only if your app is designed to have its static files served under `/static/`. If this is not the case for your app, you need to adapt that conf. Anyway this should allow you to focus your efforts on your nginx config and stop searching around docker ;)

Comment: using "alias" instead of "root" fixed it for me