# Serving static files with nginx located in another docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, static

Just to start off, I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798849/how-to-serve-static-files-with-nginx-inside-of-a-docker-container). But he/she uses `build`, and I use `image`.

I have a docker-compose file that pulls an image that I have made previously onto my server.

```
app:
  restart: always
  image: some-app-image:latest
```

nginx config

```
location /static/ {
    root /data/app/web_interface;  <--- this exists in some-app-image container
}
```

Normally, I would have a volume mounted onto the app image that contains the static files.

However, this is becoming redundant since the app container has the static files in itself.

All the nginx container needs to do is "peer" into the app container and serve those static files. Like:

```
location /static/ {
    root http://app:8000/web_interface;
}
```

or

```
location /static/ {
    root app/web_interface;
}
```

Any chance there is a way to serve static files located in another container from a nginx container?

Comment: Your container setup is a bit unclear. You have an nginx container working as a reverse proxy already serving data from your `app` container (virtual host)? Why can't the `app` container serve its own static files?

Comment: I have nginx serving static files as I don't want the gunicorn server handling them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13947418/5779280

Comment: Just to be clear: The app container runs gunicorn and your nginx container serves that though a uwsgi_pass?

Comment: More or less, a `proxy_pass` to be specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the ideas I've had in the past:

**Sharing a docker volume from app to nginx**

You can make a volume in the app's `Dockefile` and copy in the staticfiles when the container runs. Then share the volume with nginx container using `volumes_from`. This is kind of ugly and doesn't work at all if your app `depends_on` nginx. I'd say this is **definitely a no-go** as it works terribly when scale up your app container.

The idea of also mapping staticfiles from the host into the nginx container is also not optimal. You'll have an extra weird step to deal with them.

**Separate static container**

Build another nginx container serving only the static files on a different virtualhost. `static.foo.bar`.

**Use a CDN**

There are tons of CDNs out there you can put your staticfiles and most frameworks have plugins for handling that. I have some projects doing this. Works great.

**Use uWSGI**

You can serve staticfiles with uWSGI using `--static-map`. See [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StaticFiles.html). This is what I ended up doing as it was a cheap and easy... and friendly when it comes to scaling. Then you probably also need to use `http-socket` so uWSGI talks http instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer. I like the CDN option however we need to move pretty quickly and I feel like that would take a longer time to set up than the uWSGI solution.  I always thought that serving static files from the application server was a no-no.  I guess the method has evolved.

Comment: I'd say it's not optimal to serve static files from the app server, but it's not necessarily bad. If you need to move quick, that is the safe and easy way. It just works. php have been doing that for ages.

Comment: It's not perfectly clear, but one of the options (the one you not recommend) you mentioned seems to describe [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56855338/52499). Can you elaborate? Under which conditions I'm going to face issues? What kind of issues exactly?

Comment: I concur -- why is a docker volume between app and nginx bad here?

Comment: It get gets too messy when running in clustered environments in my opinon, but I'm probably a purist when it comes to docker.

Comment: I've tried a docker volume to share static files between php and nginx (for drupal) and found that its just to messy. Volumes dont get reinstalled when you recreate the container (narurally) so how to upgrade, remove volume to, but how to persist uploads... ended up with apache image as a base for my app.

Comment: One could perhaps create two Dockerfiles, one for nginx and one for the "app", copy all static content and boostrapper to nginx, and everything else to the app. Share uploads on a volume.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very late answer, but adding it in case someone else finds this.

Perhaps you could make use of server caching so that NGINX will effectively serve the static files from it's file system after the first request to the app being proxied.

[Here is a good guide to caching with NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/)

You could set the **inactive** flag to a long time as the assets are static.

*Basic example based on the guide above:*

```
proxy_cache_path /path/to/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=30d use_temp_path=off;

server {
  ...

  location /static {
    proxy_cache my_cache;
    proxy_pass http://app:8000/static; # <--- wherever static files are on app server
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the solutions is to copy assets to a shared volume on `app` service's start:

`docker-stack.yml`:

```
volumes:
  docroot:
services:
  site:
    volumes:
      - docroot:/docroot
  nginx:
    volumes:
      - docroot:/docroot
```

`app` service's `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
rsync -a --delete --exclude /uploads public/ /docroot
# start the site
```

`WORKDIR` is at `/app`. docroot at `/app/public`. Here I additionally make it not copy `uploads` dir.

More on it [here](https://github.com/x-yuri/issues/tree/docker-copy-docroot).

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar but different:

I have docker-compose running two containers: nginx and flaskapp. I have the nginx container serve static requests and forward the rest to the flask app. Here's my nginx config (flaskapp.conf):

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name $SERVER_NAME;

location ^~ /static/  {
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    root /;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://frontend:8000;
}
}
```

and the dockerfile for my nginx container:

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN mkdir static
COPY /static/ /static/
COPY flaskapp.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

I copy over a static folder that has the assets I need and now I can load them into the front end.