How to serve files in nginx from another docker container
I have a Symfony 7 project running with php-fpm 8.3 and nginx. This is the Dockerfile, for both containers (php and nginx) the working directory is /app.
I am currently uploading image files to /app/public/uploads but the file is uploaded to the php container and nginx can't serve it. Find beneath the file /etc/nginx/default.conf.template that is used in the entrypoint to run nginx in conjunction with the command envsubst '${APP_ENV} ${APP_DEBUG}'
#Dockerfile
FROM composer:2 as builder
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
ARG APP_ENV=dev
ENV composer_dev="composer install --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-scripts"
ENV composer_prod="$composer_dev --no-dev"
RUN apk add zlib-dev libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install gd && docker-php-ext-enable gd
RUN if [ "$APP_ENV" = "prod" ]; then $composer_prod; else $composer_dev; fi

FROM MyOwnTaggedImage:latest as php
COPY --link --from=builder --chown=nginx:www-data /var/www/vendor ./vendor
RUN bin/console tailwind:build --no-interaction && bin/console asset-map:compile && bin/console assets:install public
COPY docker/php/lunarlab.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/lunarlab.conf
USER nginx

FROM nginx:alpine as nginx
WORKDIR /app
COPY docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/default.conf.template
COPY ./docker/nginx/entrypoint /usr/local/bin/entrypoint
COPY --link --from=php --chown=nginx:www-data /app/public public
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint"]

#docker-compose
version: '3'

services:
  php:
    image: lunarlab/app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: php
      args:
        APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV:-dev}
    environment:
      APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV:-dev}
      # You should definitely change the APP_SECRET in production
      APP_SECRET: ${APP_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL:-pgsql://${POSTGRES_USER:-app}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}@database:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-app}}
      EMAIL: ${EMAIL}
      ADDRESS: ${ADDRESS}
      TELEPHONE: ${TELEPHONE}
      SESSION_LIFETIME: ${SESSION_LIFETIME:-3600}
      MAILER_DSN: ${MAILER_DSN:-smtp://user:pass@mailer:1025}
    volumes:
      - ./assets:/app/assets
      - ./config:/app/config
      - ./migrations:/app/migrations
      - ./templates:/app/templates
      - ./src:/app/src
      - ./translations:/app/translations
      - ./docker/php/php.ini-development:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro

    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    depends_on:
      - database

  nginx:
    image: lunarlab/nginx
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: nginx
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV:-dev}
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT:-80}:80
    # Before enabling mounting the public directory make sure to have in the local machine all the assets required by the application
    # this can be achieved by running `bin/console asset-map:compile` and `bin/console tailwind:build`
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/default.conf.template
    links:
      - php

#/etc/nginx/default.conf.template
upstream backend {
    server php:9000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    root /app/public;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost en.localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;

    #add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src data:;";
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies master-only;
    add_header Referrer-Policy same-origin;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';

    client_body_timeout 12s;
    client_header_timeout 12s;  
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    #proxy_cache_path /app/public/uploads levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=30d use_temp_path=off;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /uploads {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        proxy_pass http://backend/public/uploads; 
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV $APP_ENV;
        fastcgi_param APP_DEBUG $APP_DEBUG;

        proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;

        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|gif|jpe?g|png|htc|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
        expires 1d;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Cache-Control private;
        open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
        open_file_cache_valid 120s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 4;
        open_file_cache_errors on;
    }


    location ~*  \.(css|js)$ {
        expires 12h;
        access_log on;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

}

I am trying to achieve it with a reverse proxy but haven't been able to achieve, I would appreciate any help

Would this solution work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56855338/52499 https://github.com/x-yuri/issues/tree/docker-copy-docroot

If you add files from local dist both to nginx and php it shoudl work. In nginx docker compose add: - ./src:/app/src or better .:/app/src this way ngix has all the files and can communicate with php service
